# Randomize part of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a project involving binary patterns (here `np.arrays` of 0 and 1).
I'd like to modify a random subset of these and return several altered versions of the pattern where a given fraction of the values have been changed (like [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) a function to a random subset of an array of fixed size)
ex : take the pattern `[0 0 1 0 1]` and rate `0.2`, return `[[0 1 1 0 1] [1 0 1 0 1]]`

It seems possible by using auxiliary arrays and iterating with a condition, but is there a "clean" way to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Show the code you have

Comment: So if you have an array A of binary values, there is a probability P for each index in the array?  For example, could your pattern [0 0 1 0 1] change to [1 1 1 1 1], even though that would be improbable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=map#map) function works on boolean arrays too. You could add the subsample logic to your function, like so:

```
import numpy as np
rate = 0.2
f = lambda x: np.random.choice((True, x),1,p=[rate,1-rate])[0]

a = np.array([0,0,1,0,1], dtype='bool')
map(f, a)
# This will output array a with on average 20% of the elements changed to "1"
# it can be slightly more or less than 20%, by chance.
```

Or you could rewrite a map function, like so:

```
import numpy as np

def map_bitarray(f, b, rate):
    '''
    maps function f on a random subset of b
    :param f: the function, should take a binary array of size <= len(b)
    :param b: the binary array
    :param rate: the fraction of elements that will be replaced
    :return: the modified binary array
    '''
    c = np.copy(b)
    num_elem = len(c)
    idx = np.random.choice(range(num_elem), num_elem*rate, replace=False)
    c[idx] = f(c[idx])
    return c

f = lambda x: True
b = np.array([0,0,1,0,1], dtype='bool')
map_bitarray(f, b, 0.2)
# This will output array b with exactly 20% of the elements changed to "1"
```

Comment: Two things: First, I sometimes get the output of `[False False True False  True]` in which no elements have been changed. Second, this does not allow for `False` to be converted to `True`. The latter might not be an issue since OP was not clear on whether this should be possible.

Comment: On the first option it is -on average- 20%, that means there can be cases where more or less than 20% of elements have changed. The second option always gives you exact 20% (or whatever rate you ask). That you see `[False False True False True]` in 40% of the cases is because a `True` got set to `True` (no change). The OP can set any function he wants in the lambda, for example this one: `f = lambda x:not(x)`.

Comment: Correction: `f = lambda a: np.logical_not(x)`

Comment: Thanks, the map_bitarray was exactly what I needed! Just modified it to take int(num_elem*rate) to avoid possible errors if the rate is somewhat more exotic

Comment: Oh and careful, it needs to be range(0, num_elem) otherwise you'll never change the last element

Comment: @AFanthomme, better use `round(num_elem*rate)`, `int()` will just truncate (`int(1.9) = 1`). In my test `choice()` was alright with a float, but you're right it won't hurt to convert to int as well `int(round(..))`. You are right about that range function, I'll fix that, the `0` isn't necessary either.

Answer (score 0):

```
rate=0.2
repeats=5
seed=[0,0,1,0,1]
realizations=np.tile(seed,[repeats,1]) ^ np.random.binomial(1,rate,[repeats,len(seed)])
```

Use `np.tile()` to generate a matrix from the seed row.

`np.random.binomial()` to generate a binomial mask matrix with your requested rate.

Apply the mask with the xor binary operator `^`

---

EDIT:

Based on @Jared Goguen comments, if you want to change 20% of the bits, you can elaborate a mask by choosing elements to change randomly:

```
seed=[1,0,1,0,1]

rate=0.2
repeats=10

mask_list=[]

for _ in xrange(repeats):
  y=np.zeros(len(seed),np.int32)
  y[np.random.choice(len(seed),0.2*len(seed))]=1
  mask_list.append(y)

mask = np.vstack(mask_list)
realizations=np.tile(seed,[repeats,1]) ^ mask
```

Comment: It should be noted that this does not change a proportion of 0.2 of the entries, instead every element has a 0.2 chance of changing. The mean rearrangement will have a proportion of 0.2 elements changed, but each rearrangement may have anywhere between no elements changed and all elements changed. This implementation perfectly models a structure where each element has an *independent* transition probability, but if it is known that an 5-array with two 1's will go to a 5-array with three 1's, it fails.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. The other case would be modelled with a Markov chain, isn't it?

Comment: With a Markov chain, the transition matrix is composed of the probabilities of each state transitioning to each other state. By definition, the sum of the state vector is invariant in this process, so I don't really see a way to model this using Markov chains. There might be a way to use a similar process, but the transition matrix would not be stochastic.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's already an answer that provides sequences where each element has a random transition probability. However, it seems like you might want an exact fraction of the elements to change instead. For example, `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]` can change to `[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]` or `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`, but not `[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]`.

The premise, based off of xvan's answer, uses the bit-wise xor operator `^`. When a bit is xor'd with 0, it's value will not change. When a bit is xor'd with 1, it will flip. From your question, it seems like you want to change `len(seq)*rate` number of bits in the sequence. First create `mask` which contains `len(seq)*rate` number of 1's. To get an altered sequence, xor the original sequence with a shuffled version of `mask`.

Here's a simple, inefficient implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def edit_sequence(seq, rate, count):
    length = len(seq)
    change = int(length * rate)
    mask = [0]*(length - change) + [1]*change
    return [seq ^ np.random.permutation(mask) for _ in range(count)]

rate = 0.2
seq = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])

print edit_sequence(seq, rate, 5) 

# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
# [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I don't really know much about NumPy, so maybe someone with more experience can make this efficient, but the approach seems solid.

**Edit:** Here's a version that times about 30% faster:

```
def edit_sequence(seq, rate, count):
    mask = np.zeros(len(seq), dtype=int)
    mask[:len(seq)*rate] = 1
    output = []
    for _ in range(count):
        np.random.shuffle(mask)
        output.append(seq ^ mask)
    return output
```

It appears that this updated version scales very well with the size of `seq` and the value of `count`. Using `dtype=bool` in `seq` and `mask` yields another 50% improvement in the timing.